# Website is a different layout on different browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a website but when I simulate it in IE5.5, IE6 & IE7 they layout and everything looks aweful compared to what it should. It works perfectly on IE8 & IE9. 
My question is, is there a script which automatically fixes the layout issues depending what browser the user is using?

Comment: You could try [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)...But it all depends on what's not working. Custom css targeting IE is better options

Comment: Who really cares about IE5.5 at all?  Even IE6 support can pretty much be tossed out unless you live in China or something.

Comment: @cHao I agree it is just IE7 im worried about

Answer (score 1):

There is no script, you will have to create a separate .css file and detect the browser. Sorry but IE is terrible at staying consistent.

Something link this

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
Special instructions for IE 7 here
Or use a different .css file here. 
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```